# Configure auto import in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure vscode auto import (or a plugin) for typescript to look like:

```
import * as foo from './foo'
```

Instead of:

```
import { a, b, c } from './foo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of VS Code 1.44 (TypeScript 3.9) this is not supported. However auto imports will try to re-use a namespace import if one already exists and there is a refactoring to convert between import styles (just select the import to use it).

[This feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19630) tracks adding an option to use namespace imports by default